# Find multiple cell values in column A and replace with variable values in column D of same row

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched high and low for something close to this to get me started with the VBA code, but I keep striking out.  I'm having a bit of a writers block, and could use any help.

I'm trying to write a macro that will find multiple specific values in column A and replace the contents of column D in that row with specific values.

Basically it's going to be a price override function for specific SKUs.  The SKUs are populated in column A, and the prices are populated in column D.  It's only 6 SKUs, but I can't quite figure this one out.

It has to be a macro because I am manipulating a file that is fetched fresh twice a day.  I use a sort of master macro sheet to open this file and then manipulate the data.

Thanks as always in advance!  I appreciate the help!

Edited to add:

Here's something I tried, but I can't figure out how to do this for multiple values, etc.

```
Sub Test()
Cells.Find(What:="26860", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("D1704").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "63.94"
Range("D1705").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: show us please what have you tried so far

Comment: Try to avoid accessing Excel. It is VERY slow. That is why I read and write in blocks. Select is also VERY slow. Here is more information on optimization: http://www.soa.org/news-and-publications/newsletters/compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a very optimized way of manipulation of data in VBA:
In this example I merge the values of A and D and put it in E. You can just change the formula for your application

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim cellsArray() As Variant
cellsArray = Range("A1:A20").value
Dim cells2Array() As Variant
cells2Array = Range("D1:D20").value
For i = LBound(cellsArray, 1) To UBound(cellsArray, 1)
   ' Put your code here
   cellsArray(i,1) = cellsArray(i,1) & cells2Array(i,1)
Next i
Range("E1:E20").value = cellsArray

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I was obviously way too tired to be thinking about writing code because I couldn't remember the most simple solution:

```
 For Each Cel In Range("A2:A3000")
   If Cel.Value = "Number" Then Cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Othernumber"
 Next
```

Yikes.  That's embarrassing!  =p